# ng-grid with manually handle page index changed

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an example of ng-grid server side pagination from here : http://ddeloy.com/angular-ng-grid-example/server-side-page/index.html

However as the original purpose of pagination.. i do NOT want to load the entire records from the server..  I am passing the page size and index to the server code so I need to be able to handle the click event of page index change (previous and next page button).. how can i do this with ng-grid?

Comment: Try the [***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/50vJrs?p=preview) from the [***ng-grid docs***](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)

Comment: @JasonGoemaat--  the plunker is not what i'm after.. in fact it is actually the same link (http://ddeloy.com/angular-ng-grid-example/server-side-page/index.html) and it is real issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the same link that you have provided you can see that the pageSize and index are handled in a watch, so you can call your server side function from there, something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function () {
    $http.post('/get_records', {"page_size": $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,
                                "page_index": $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage}
    ).success(function (serverPagedData) {
        $scope.myData = serverpagedData;
        $scope.pagingOptions.totalServerItems = serverPagedData.length;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}, true);
```

Cheers!